# How can I override the registration page?

Tags: magento-1.9, template, overrides, register

I'm trying to add phone and address fields to the account registration form, as per this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420604/add-default-telephone-field-in-customer-registration-form-in-magento).

To override the core functionality, I copied **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml** to  **app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml**, as would be expected.

The problem is that no changes are detected when added to the new template, not even simple changes such as editing field labels.  Stranger still, not even changes made to the core template are detected.

I have verified the file paths are correct, including namespace, and made sure file ownership and permissions are correct.

I have cleared the Magento cache many times (all of it), and even tried viewing the page in incognito mode and with other browsers to rule out browser cache.  Also, there is no caching at the server level.

Am I missing something?  I've successfully overridden core template files numerous times before, but is there something more that I need to do for the registration form templates?

Comment: Did you make files that cofig file of your module and xml file for declaring module to Magento?

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Do I need to make a module (extension?) in order to override the registration form?  I'm not adding fields that don't exist, simply editing an existing template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are making changes to wrong files. The correct file for registration form should be

**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml**

So copy the file in your theme

**app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml**

And it should work.