# Magento1.9 registration page

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-registration

I want to change my customer registration page to a under construction page. I use magento 1.9.
for example, when customer goes to customer/account/create see just a text not any form

Comment: You can override the registration page and disable the form and set custom message. Check this post for reference if it helps! https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166102/how-can-i-override-the-registration-page

Comment: @MGPM, did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by two ways:

**1** - Set new template and remove default registration form

Add following code at:

app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/customer.xml

```
<customer_account_create>
    <remove name="customer_form_register"/>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="uc" template="customer/uc.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

Create `uc.phtml` at:

> app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/customer/uc.phtml

**2** - Override phtml at theme level and remove form and add you new content

copy following from:

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/customer/form/register.phtml

Hope above will help!